# Replacing values in nested NSDictionary duplicates values in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am replacing values in a nested NSDictionary, but once I do that it duplicates the number of items in my NSArray. It contains the old entries, plus the newly modified ones:

```
        SharedManager *manager = [SharedManager shared];
        NSMutableArray *array = [manager.items mutableCopy];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *notes in [manager.items mutableCopy]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            tempDictionary = [notes mutableCopy];
            [tempDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:@"key"];
            [array addObject:tempDictionary];
        }

        DebugLog(@"%@", [manager items]);
```

I would simply like my old NSArray to be replaced with the newly modified one.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the `array` object after the loop. You're not assigning it back to anything (ie manager.items)-- do you mean to?

Comment: Yeah, because the array is an immutable object so I that's why I created a new one.

Comment: Right, but I mean, when you debug log `manager.items` at the end, you're just dumping the original array. Your code snippet shows you doing a bunch of work on `array` and then throwing it away without changing manager to point to it. Do you want a `manager.items = array;` after the loop?

Comment: The code is full of redundancy. You create an additional mutableCopy of your array in the for statement and you allocate and initialise a mutable dictionary on each iteration only throw it away on the next line and then as @BenZotto said you don't do anything with the `array`. But assuming that that was an oversight, you are calling `addObject` on `array` so of course you will have more elements. What are you actually trying to achieve? It looks like you should use an integer array iteration rather than fast enumeration so that you can update the index rather than calling addObject

Answer (score 0):

Array receives all the items here

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [manager.items mutableCopy];
```

then, you add it again at

```
[array addObject:tempDictionary];
```

the first line should be replaced by

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably do this much more simply. If `manager.items` is an array of mutable dictionaries like the code implies, then you can update the dictionaries without changing the (immutable) array that holds them:

```
SharedManager *manager = [SharedManager shared];
for (NSMutableDictionary *notes in manager.items)  // loop through every dict in the array 
    [notes setObject:@1 forKey:@"key"];            // update dict in-place
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a new array and reassign it at the end to `manager.items`.

```
SharedManager *manager = [SharedManager shared];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *notes in manager.items) {
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [notes mutableCopy];
    [tempDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:@"key"];
    [array addObject:tempDictionary];
}

manager.items = [array copy]; // make it immutable again
DebugLog(@"%@", [manager items]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start your new array from scratch, rather than with the copy of existing one + I would suggest to remove redundant `mutableCopy` calls:

```
SharedManager *manager = [SharedManager shared];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *notes in manager.items) {
    NSMutableDictionary* newNotes = [notes mutableCopy];
    [newNotes setObject:@1 forKey:@"key"];
    [array addObject:newNotes];
}
```